# Bank Program error when I try to access an account that does not exist

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have been working on this bank program for my Java class at school for the past week and a half. I thought I finally had it working the way my instructor wanted. However, when I try to access an account that does not exist, the program "blows up" (my instructors words). I need it to let the user know that the account does not exist and redirect them back to the main menu. So, my problem I believe is in my *findAcct* method in my Bank class. I have tried several fixes but none have worked. Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated! I need to have this done by Monday. I know I said the problem is in one method, but I'll post my whole program for context.

Bank Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bank 
{
private int max = 25;
private int count;
bankAcct myAcct[] = new bankAcct[max];
Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);

  public void openAcct()
  {
      if (count >= max){
        System.out.println("Not accepting new customers at this time.");
      }else{
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        String lname = scannerObject.next();
        myAcct[count] = new bankAcct(count + 1, 25, lname);
        count++;
        System.out.println("Thank you " + lname + ", your account number is: " + count);
        }

  }

  public int findAcct() // This is the method in question
  {
      int found = -1;
      System.out.println("Greetings, please enter your account number: ");
      found = scannerObject.nextInt();
      for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      if(myAcct[i].getAcctNum() == found){
          found = i;
          }
       }          
       return found;          
  }




  public void seeBal()
  {
      int lfound = findAcct();
      if (lfound == -1){
          System.out.println("Error!");
      }else{
          myAcct[lfound].dispBal();
          }
  }

  public void Deposit()
  {
      int lfound = findAcct();
      if (lfound == -1){
          System.out.println("Error!");
      }else{
          myAcct[lfound].makeDeposit();
          }
  }

  public void Withdrawal()
  {
      int lfound = findAcct();
      if (lfound == -1){
          System.out.println("Error!");
      }else{
          myAcct[lfound].makeWithdrawal();
          }
  } 
}
```

bankAcct Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bankAcct 
{
private double Bal;
private int acctNum;
private String name;
Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);

public bankAcct(int pAcctNum, double pBal, String pName) 
{
    Bal = pBal;
    acctNum = pAcctNum;
    name = pName;
}   

    public void makeDeposit()
    {
        System.out.print( "Hello " + name + ", please, enter amount to deposit $");
        double lDep = scannerObject.nextDouble();
        Bal = Bal + lDep;
        System.out.println( " You have deposited $" + lDep);
        System.out.println( " Your new balance is $" + Bal);
    }

    public void makeWithdrawal()
    {
        System.out.print( "Hello " + name + ", please, enter amount to withdraw $");
        double lWDraw = scannerObject.nextDouble();
        if (lWDraw <= Bal){
            Bal = Bal - lWDraw;
            System.out.println( "You have withdrawn $" + lWDraw);
            System.out.println( "Your new balance is $" + Bal);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Insufficient funds!");
             }
    }

    public void dispBal()
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello " + name + ", your current balance is $" + Bal);
    }


        public int getAcctNum()
        {
            return acctNum;
        }

        public void setName(String pName)
        {
            name = pName;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }


}
```

bankUser Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bankUser 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 

{
    Bank myBank = new Bank();

    int Choice; 

    do
    {
    dispMenu();

    Choice = getChoice();

    proChoice(Choice, myBank);
    }   
    while (Choice !=0);
}

public static void dispMenu()
{
    System.out.println( "|==================================|");
    System.out.println( "|    TONY'S FIRST NATIONAL BANK    |");
    System.out.println( "|***********Menu Options***********|");
    System.out.println( "|__________________________________|");
    System.out.println( "|  Press [1] To Open New Account   |");
    System.out.println( "|  Press [2] To View Balance       |");
    System.out.println( "|  Press [3] To Make Deposit       |");
    System.out.println( "|  Press [4] To Make Withdrawal    |");
    System.out.println( "|  Press [0] to Exit               |");
    System.out.println( "|__________________________________|");
    System.out.println( "|   Please Make Selection Now...   |");
    System.out.println( "|==================================|");
}

static int getChoice()
{
    Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);
    int pChoice, Choice;
    pChoice = scannerObject.nextInt();  
    Choice = pChoice;
    return Choice;
}

static void proChoice(int Choice, Bank myBank)
{
    switch (Choice)
    {
        case 1: myBank.openAcct();
        break;      
        case 2: myBank.seeBal();
        break;
        case 3: myBank.Deposit();
        break;
        case 4: myBank.Withdrawal();
        break;
        case 0: System.out.println( "Thank you, come again.");
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated. I am still a padawan when it comes to Java.

*UPDATE: I have tried this code, and it seems to work! However, my instructor told me that we can never have 2 return statements within a method.

```
public int findAcct()
  {
      int found = -1;
      System.out.println("Greetings, please enter your account number: ");
      found = scannerObject.nextInt();
      for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      if(myAcct[i].getAcctNum() == found){
          return found = i;
          }
       }          
      return -1;
  }
```

UPDATE: Here is what I did to my findAcct method in my Bank Class:

```
public int findAcct()
  {
      System.out.println("Greetings, please enter your account number: ");
      int acctNum = scannerObject.nextInt();
      int found = -1;
      for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){  
          if(myAcct[i].getAcctNum() == acctNum){
              found = i;
              break; //Ends Loop
          }
      }     
      return found; 
  }
```

My instructor did not mind a break statement, so I added out at the end of my for loop. I also moved my local variable found = -1; down a couple lines. Thank you for all the help! I can't wait to learn more!

Comment: Do you have a programming problem you'd like help with?  I can see a lot of code but no question. Step through it with a debugger and see where it goes wrong if you actually have a problem.   By the way, your instructor is wrong. You have have many return statements in a method.

Comment: That's what I have been seeing and hearing. But, I guess it is just her preference. My question is, how can I have this method perform the same action without 2 returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to have 2 return statements within a method (which you can have, but sometimes it is bad practice when you are beginning coding so professors like to just make that rule) you can use your found variable to store the value that will be returned and return `found` at the end of the function.

You were on the right track.

Example:

```
public int findAcct()
  {
      int found = -1;
      System.out.println("Greetings, please enter your account number: ");
      found = scannerObject.nextInt();
      for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      if(myAcct[i].getAcctNum() == found){
           found = i;
           break; //Exit out of the loop 
          }
       }          
      return found;
  }
```

This code will set `found` to `i` if it finds the account and then `break` out of the loop. After it breaks out of the loop it will return found. Otherwise, found will never be set and return -1 since you initialized it to -1 at the top.

If your instructor has not taught you `break` statements yet, then you can use a boolean variable `foundAccount` initialized to false. Then check if foundAccount is false before doing your if statement check. Once you find it, set it to true so you do not keep looking.

**Example:**

```
public int findAcct()
  {
      int found = -1;
      boolean foundMatch = false;
      System.out.println("Greetings, please enter your account number: ");
      found = scannerObject.nextInt();
      for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      if(!foundMatch){
      if(myAcct[i].getAcctNum() == found){
           found = i;
           foundMatch = true; //we will no longer search
          }
       }
       }          
      return found;
  }
```

Comment: If an instructor doesn't like 2 returns, he'll probably not like breaks either :D

Comment: Heh, that is true. I have added a quick rough update to help with that if that is the case :P.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try. We were taught about breaks in a case selection but not much more than that lol. We have discussed boolean so that may suffice. Thank you again!

Comment: Great, I have added an example for using boolean. Be sure to understand it and if it helps solve your problem do not forget to upvote and/or accept the answer for future users.

Comment: When I do this, I am still getting an error. NullPointerException error. Am I maybe doing something wrong in my seeBal, Withdraw, etc. methods?? When I choose view balance for an account that does not yet exist, it points to line 47 in my Bank class which is myAcct[lfound].dispBal();

Comment: This is a good time to learn how to debug, a quick and dirty way to debug this issue is in your seeBal method print out "lfound" after you findAccount() and see what value you get. For some reason you are not getting -1.

Comment: You're right! It's not getting -1 at all... I will try and find my error. I need to learn this stuff anyway. Thanks for all your help!